# Canvasに描画できない領域ができてしまう

Tags: javascript

GameAppに width 1024, height 768を指定しているのですが、実際に描画すると、width 800ぐらいの辺りまでしか描画できません。
この原因としては何が考えられるでしょうか？

```
phina.define('MainScene', {
    superClass: 'DisplayScene',
    init: function () {
        this.superInit();

        for (var row = 0; row < 32; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col < 48; col++) {
                var chipImage = "ground";
                if (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 0) {
                    chipImage = "grassland"
                }
                this.bg = Sprite(chipImage).addChildTo(this);
                this.bg.setPosition(32 * col, 32 * row);
                this.bg.origin.set(0, 0);
            }
        }
    },
});

// メイン処理
phina.main(function () {
    var app = GameApp({
        startLabel: 'main',
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        assets: ASSETS
    });

    app.enableStats();
    app.run();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sceneにもwidth, heightを渡してあげればOK！

```
phina.define('MainScene', {
    superClass: 'DisplayScene',
    init: function () {
        this.superInit( // Sceneにもwidth, height を与える！
            {
                width : 1024,
                height 768
            }
        );

        for (var row = 0; row < 32; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col < 48; col++) {
                var chipImage = "ground";
                if (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 0) {
                    chipImage = "grassland"
                }
                this.bg = Sprite(chipImage).addChildTo(this);
                this.bg.setPosition(32 * col, 32 * row);
                this.bg.origin.set(0, 0);
            }
        }
    },
});

// メイン処理
phina.main(function () {
    var app = GameApp({
        startLabel: 'main',
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        assets: ASSETS
    });

    app.enableStats();
    app.run();
});
```